# Having an XPath how to check if it will try to match element or attribute?

Tags: c#, javascript, xpath, attributes, element

What I really need is a method for identifying if an XPath 2.0 expression is referred to element(s) or attribute(s).

Suppose a method with the following prototype:

```
XPathResultType IdentifyXPathResultType (string xpath)
```

For input like

```
//Parent[@id='1']/Children/child[@name]
```

the method should return something like

```
XPathResultType.Element
```

For input like

```
//Parent[@id='1']/Children/child/@name
```

the method should return something like

```
XPathResultType.Attribute
```

**The above example is simple to implement but XPath 2.0 has many features and a smart parser needs to be implemented.**

Is there any library or facility in Javascript that can accomplish such thing?

I really need this for client side with Javascript.

*Also solutions in C# for .NET are acceptable.*

Answer (score 0):

XPath 2.0 defines a `instance of` operator. This way you can test something like

```
//Parent[@id='1']/Children/child/@name instance of attribute()
```

which in this case will yield `true`. Depending on what XPath parser you are using, you might be able to define your own function, which then could test for the different element types and return a appropriate response item.

If not, you could also run the XPath several times, each time tesing against a different data type. However, this sounds less than optimal, so the first option is preferred.

Comment: This is a nice approach that it seems to work, but I cannot use it since I have to test the XPath expression with a context which is a document or an element. What I'm having is just the XPath expression. The data or the structure that the XPath is referred to are dynamic. Any other solution?

Comment: hmm, then it is quite difficult. I would most likely try to get a Query plan and analyze this. Using BaseX you can get the query plan and then can analyze the last axis step and get the attribute type. There is a .Net binding for Basex called nxdb, which you could use.

Comment: Otherwise, your only bet seems to be to really write your own parser. This, however, will require quite some resources as it is not that easily done.

Comment: also, most likely you can also use other XPath/XQuery processors, BaseX is just the one I am most familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Saxon as your XPath parser then after parsing the expression you will be able to dig down to the Expression object which has a getItemType() method giving the information you are looking for. Details depend on what platform you are running on.

Comment: Can you please provide me with an example? Please take account that the only information that I am having is the XPath expression as a string value. Nothing more. There is no document of XML to "test" the XPath expression. However, I know that the expression is a valid XPath expression. Also, if you had a solution with client-side code like Javascript it would be fantastic.

Comment: At present I can't see a way to do this with the APIs on Saxon-CE. With C# you would have to make direct calls on methods in the (Java) saxon9.dll module. Create an expression using net.sf.saxon.sxpath.XPathEvaluator.createExpression, and then get its type using getInternatExpression().getItemType().

Comment: Please let me know. In my application I use only elements and attributes so I created the following regular expression to match the XPath expression: "(/@[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?!.*[\p{P}].*))|(/@[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?!.*[\p{P}].*))|(@[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?!.*[\p{P}].*))|(@[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?!.*[\p{P}].*))". Assuming that there is no match then it is an element, otherwise it is an attribute. Do you like it people? Could we make it a little better?

Comment: If you want a crude heuristic that's going to get it right most of the time, rather than an accurate solution, then it could be a lot simpler than that and probably just as good - just check whether there's an "@" sign that isn't within square brackets.

Comment: Can you please give me an example in Javascript?

Comment: Javascript has no native implementation of negative lookbehind regular expression matching.

Comment: I have done it with Javascript with the following regular expression: "(\/@[a-zA-Z][\w]*:[a-zA-Z][\w]*(?!.*[\W].*))|(\/@[a-zA-Z][\w]*(?!.*[\W].*))|(@[a-zA-Z][\w]*:[a-zA-Z][\w]*(?!.*[\W].*))|(@[a-zA-Z][\w]*(?!.*[\W].*))". This matches namespaces also.

Comment: So long as you recognize it's an approximation, that's fine. For example it fails if the attribute axis is spelt "attribute::" rather than "@". So don't use this approach if it needs to be right all the time.